# Finding the equation of plane that is transformed to a line

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Suppose I have a transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ and its matrix: $$T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\ 
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I am told that there is a plane being transformed to a line of the equation $x-y=0$. And I want to find out the equation of the plane.

I thought I could first express the plane in its explicit form:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x\\ 
y
\end{bmatrix}=t
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix} ,t\in\mathbb{R}$$
And then make the transformation equate to it:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 & 1\\ 
-1 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_{plane}\\ 
y_{plane}\\ 
z_{plane}
\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1
\end{bmatrix}$$
Solve for its solution space:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_{plane}\\ 
y_{plane}\\ 
z_{plane}
\end{bmatrix}=
t\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
2\\
1
\end{bmatrix}+
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
-2\\
0
\end{bmatrix},t\in\mathbb{R}$$

But this is obviously wrong because first, this is a line and second, this is not an implicit equation of the plane.

What should I do to get the equation(implicit form) of the plane that is transformed to the line $x-y=0$?

Comment: I'll take a guess. The right hand side of your third displayed equation should be $[{t\atop t}]$. The solution set should be of the form $u{\bf v_1}+t{\bf v_2}$ ($u$ will be the free variable of the $2x3$ matrix).

Comment: The third display should not have the $t$. It was a typo. I have edited it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you should see what happens to the coordinates. $T\pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = \pmatrix{x+y-z\\z-x} =\pmatrix{t\\t}$. Start by replacing $z-x = m$, then you get $\pmatrix{y-m\\m}=\pmatrix{t\\t}$.

Comment: @percusse ohh...thank you!!

Comment: @xEnOn No problem at all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the points in ${\mathbb R}^3$ by $(z_1,z_2,z_3)$ and the points in the plane ${\mathbb R}^2$ by $(x,y)$. When $T:\ (z_1,z_2,z_3)\mapsto(x,y)$ then by the rules of linear algebra

$$\left[\matrix{x\cr y\cr}\right]= \left[\matrix{1 &-1&1 \cr -1&0&1\cr}\right]\ 
\left[\matrix{z_1\cr z_2\cr z_3}\right] =
\left[\matrix{z_1-z_2+z_3\cr -z_1 +z_3\cr}\right]\ .$$

Now the question is: Which equation must the $z_k$ satisfy such that $x-y=0\ $? As $x-y=2z_1-z_2$ it follows that $x-y=0$ iff $2z_1-z_2=0$; and the last equation is the equation of the plane in ${\mathbb R}^3$ that gets mapped onto the line $x=y$.